# Simplicial Homology: The definition of cycles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to convince myself beyond a doubt that $n$-cycles should be defined as elements of $\ker \partial _n$. My intuition is along the lines of "a cycle is a boundary of some chain (not necessarily in the simplicial complex $K$), so all I really know is that its own boundary is zero because $\partial ^2=0$." My problem is that $\partial$ is itself only defined on chains of simplices in $K$, so really I'm not, in general, applying $\partial ^2$, and I can't justify the definition as I'd like.

What's a better way to carefully justify this definition?

---

***Added:***

I guess my phrasing was unclear, so I'll try to ask my question better. In Rotman's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, the author says something along the lines of:

> Some $n$-chains ought to be boundaries of a union of some $n$-simplices (*not necessarily in the complex*) - call these $n$-cycles. Some $n$-chains are boundaries of things *in the complex* - call these $n$-boundaries.

I'm trying to understand how the formal definitions fit this description. In the case of $n$-boundaries, it's clear why they should be defined as elements of $\text{im }\partial_{n+1}$, since that means - by definition - they are boundaries of some $(n+1)$-chain. What I don't understand, is how $\ker \partial _n$ captures the $n$-chains that are boundaries of "something" not necessarily in the complex (e.g boundaries of holes).

My question is how does $\ker \partial _n$ capture the right $n$-chains.

Comment: @Pedro I am not saying a cycle is always a boundary of something *in the complex*, merely that it's a boundary of "something". This is how Rotman presents cycles and bondaries in Introduction to Homological Algebra

Comment: I cannot understand what's troubling you.

Comment: @Pedro I'm looking for a precise explanation of why cycles are defined as elements of the kernel

Comment: The best explanation will frankly involve doing a lot of examples. So write down a bunch of simplicial complexes (I suggest eg the circle, figure 8, sphere, torus) and look at what some of the simplest cycles look like. Convince yourself these should be called cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with 1-cycles.

The canonical example of a 1-cycle is an oriented simple closed curve $\gamma$ in the 1-skeleton of the simplicial complex, subdivided into 0-cells and oriented 1-simplices. Notice that each 0-simplex in the simplicial complex has exactly the same number of incoming oriented 1-simplices as it has outgoing oriented 1-simplices: that number is either 1 or 0 depending on whether the given 0-simplex is or is not a point on $\gamma$. It follows that $\gamma$ is in the kernel of $\partial$, in other words $\gamma$ satisfies the definition of a 1-cycle.

Now, one wants 1-cycles to be closed under addition and multiplication by coefficients. So, one wants to be able to add up a linear combination of arbitrary simple closed curves and still have a 1-cycle. Fortunately the kernel of $\partial$ is closed under arbitrary linear combinations so this works.

Finally, one can go one step further and show that anything in the kernel of $\partial$ can be rewritten as a sum of a finite number of oriented simple closed curves (using integer coefficients) or as a linear combination of oriented simple closed curves (using real coefficients).

To summarize, the definition of a 1-cycle is crafted so that the things that we think of intuitively as "1-cycles", namely the oriented simple closed curves, indeed satisfy the definition, and in fact they generate the whole group of 1-cycles in a very concrete sense.

Having said that, one then steps away from the intuitive concept of "oriented simple closed curves" and adopts the definition of 1-cycles with glad heart, because really it is much easier to work with.

---

Now one can do something similar with 2-cycles. One might try to use embedded oriented 2-manifolds in the 2-skeleton as the canonical examples of 2-cycles. This does not quite work out, unfortunately; think of the 2-complex obtained by pinching the north and south poles of the 2-sphere to a single point. Instead, for the canonical examples can work with local embeddings of oriented 2-manifolds in the 2-skeleton. With a little work, a bit more than in the 1-dimensional case, one can show that each of these canonical examples is a 2-cycle, and that the general 2-cycle is a sum of 2-cycles each of which is one of the canonical examples.

---

This might be enough for you to now see how the definition of $n$-cycles is formulated, as an abstraction of the definitions when $n=1$ and $2$. One interesting and strange thing that happens, is that it is no longer true that one can use immersed oriented $n$-manifolds as the canonical examples of $n$-cycles, but that is a much deeper issue.

Comment: Thanks! I found a very similar explanation in chapter 2 of Hatcher.